# Convert all functions to asynchronous quickly in VS Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, async-await

I'm building a web app. For my back-end, I ended up creating many different functions. Only later— when I started setting up my API— did I realize that I wanted all my functions to be asynchronous.

I probably should've had better foresight, but now I am stuck with many different functions that I do not want to manually change. The only progress I made was to find all instances of `def` and replace it with `async def`. This worked but as I am working with Python, the problem is with the `await` keyword.

Is there any quick way to convert all functions like this

```py
example_function(arguments)
```

to this?

```py
await example_function(arguments)
```

I want to quickly add await to all functions regardless of the name. This is a problem as my functions have varying names and replacing most common instances would break my app. I am working with Python in VS Code.

Comment: You could import the file that contains all the definition from another script, list all the asynchronous functions names (with `dir` and astute type checking), then for each name replace `"{name}"` with `"await {name}"` in your original script. I'm sure someone at ease with `ast` can figure out an easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on regex matching for the editor find-and-replace feature, then use the following search input:

```
([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9-_]*|[a-zA-Z_]+)\(.*\)
```

and the following replacement field:

```
await $0
```

You could *maybe* use the "Replace All" action ([image]/[image] button or keyboard shortcut), but I'd be more confident going through it one by one. There might be false positives. I highly doubt *every* single function call you make in a file is to an asynchronous function (especially calls to ones that you didn't write).

The `$0` in the replacement field means "the whole thing that was matched".

Comment: All my functions indeed were not asynchronous, stuff like ".replace" and "enumerate" was being replaced.  Also, I just had to do "await $0" instead of "async $0" because my problem was with the awaits, not the asyncs, which were already fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @rabbibillclinton whoops. the async was an artifact of an older revision where I misunderstood the question. fixed it now.